# How do I specify == $0 in css?

Tags: css

I have two classes with the same exact name and nothing to differentiate them except for "== $0" on the end of the class.

This is the html

```
<html>
      <body>
             <div tabindex="0" class="Test" role="button"> == $0

             <div tabindex="0" class="Test" role="button">
      </body>
</html>
```

I want to select the "== $0" in css.

Comment: You have two divs, one empty and one with some text, right?

Comment: Where are your closing tags to be positioned in this scenario.

Comment: They are not inside each other they are in different classes with the same exact names

Comment: share a valid and complete HTML so we can better understand. This is actualy not a *complete* HTML code

Comment: You're not closing them, so it's up to your browser to take a guess on the structure. But they are not 'in' classes anyway. Once properly closed, you can use `:first-child` or `:nth-child(2)` to select one of them. You cannot select them by their concrete content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to express `== $0` in CSS. It means "Is currently selected in the DOM Inspector in the Chrome developer tools".

[image: Demo of == $0 moving]

Comment: Oh ok but how do I specify one or the other if there is no difference between classes

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is only for Chrome developer tools.

Comment: @Gaming4me — If the two elements are identical, then the only way to distinguish between them in CSS is by using combinators to describe their relationships to other elements.

Comment: @DreamTeK It is the same in Firefox and Safari. Just the UI is slightly different.

Comment: How do I check the classes inside the class to check if it is the right class

Comment: @Gaming4me — There is no combinator that can [select an element based on its descendants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to select the element based on its contents using CSS. There simply is no selector for that.

If you're not looking at the content, you can still differentiate between the two elements, by checking where they are in their parent, or where they are related to other elements.

**Children of their parent**

For instance, you can use `:first-child`, or the more generic `:nth-child(x)` to get a specific child, so `.Test:first-child` will select only the .Test div that is the first child of its parent. It won't select the other one.

```css
.Test:first-child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.Test:nth-child(2) {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="Test" role="button"> == $0</div>
<div tabindex="0" class="Test" role="button"></div>
```

**Looking at their siblings**

Alternatively, you can use the `~` combinator to look for siblings:

```css
.Test {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

/* A .Test that is following another .Test */
.Test ~ .Test {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="Test" role="button"> == $0</div>
<div tabindex="0" class="Test" role="button"></div>
```